# Reasons that equivalence of metrics is important in this question

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Question: is there a metric $\rho$ equivalent to the Euclidean metric
>   on $\Bbb{Q}$ such that ($\Bbb{Q},\rho$) is complete?

I used Baire's theorem: $\Bbb{Q}$ is a countable union of subsets - all the singletons $\{q\}$ such that $q\in\Bbb{Q}$. In a metric equivalent to the Euclidean metric, these are nowhere-dense sets, therefore ($\Bbb{Q},\rho$) can't be complete.

I was wandering where the equivalence to the Euclidean metric was necessary in that problem. I thought only about the nowhere-density of the singletons. In a discrete metric, for example, $\{q\}$ is both an open and a closed set. Since $\{q\}$ is open and contains $q$, it is a surrounding of $q$ by definition. So there exists an open set in $\Bbb{Q}$ such that it has no subset which doesn't contain any points of $\{q\}$. So $\{q\}$ isn't nowhere-dense in $\Bbb{Q}$ and Baire's theorem isn't relevant.

Are there any other important point to notice? Is my way of reasoning suitable to this kind of problems? I am new to topology and I feel like I stick too much to definitions and don't have a "feel" for them. Any suggestions?

Comment: By equivalence do you mean something like $c_1 \rho(x, y) \le |x-y| \le c_2 \rho(x, y)$?

Comment: @ArcticChar yes.

Comment: To be clear: do you mean: There is $c_1, c_2$ so that the above inequality holds for all $x, y$?

Comment: @ArcticChar I don't think this is what the question meant. The definition you give is for *strong* equivalence. I don't think it is needed here.

Comment: Great, then part of my answer does not make sense. I will delete the answer but you have to unaccept it first.

Comment: @ArcticChar I did. But what part of it doesn't make sense?

Comment: The last part in aside. (And the second formulation of your question).

Comment: @ArcticChar okay. I'm sorry that my question wasn't clear enough. Your answer and the discussion that followed did teach me new things. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no problems with your reasoning. And many students have to be repeatedly told to use the def'ns.

There are other ways to show that $\mathbb Q$ is not completely metrizable. Example:

Theorem. If $X $ is non-empty, completely metrizable, and has no isolated points then $X$ has a subspace homeomorphic to the Cantor set. In particular, $X$ must be uncountable. But $\mathbb Q$ is only countable.

Considering $\mathbb Q$ to be just a countably infinite set, there are many different kinds of topologies on it. The discrete topology on any set (in which all subsets are open) is always completely metrizable, as we can let $d(p,q)=1$ when $p\ne q.$